# Will calling mysql_connect() and mysql_close() 16 times causing high DB connections?

Tags: php, performance, joomla1.5, mysql-5.1

I have a Joomla1.5 based system. I run the profiler and found that mysql_connect() and mysql_close() both functions have been used 16 times. 
**I know that both of these functions and Joomla 1.5 are deprecated and strongly prohibited by the community.**
My system is facing performance issue and sometimes during peak hours DB connection threads become too high (>100) and system running slower. While we have a dedicated Windows server.

```
Below is my DB server configuration:
Windows edition: Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard Service Pack 1
Processor: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X5460 @3.16GHZ 3.16 GHZ (2 Processors)
Installed Memory(RAM): 8.00 GB
System type: 64-Bit Operating system
```

**mysql_connect()** function has been used in the constructor of **JDatabaseMySQL** class. It means whenever we create database object, this mysql_connect() is getting executed and create a new connection.

- I am curious to know whether calling mysql_connect() function multiple times creating such high DB connection threads issue?
- Is it possible to use a single connection instead of initiating objects so
  many times? If yes, how can I do that?
- Will Replacement of mysql_connection() by mysqli_connect() help us in the improvement of system performance?
- How Joomla manages the connection pool?

Please provide your answer without suggesting upgrading Joomla.

Answer (score 3):

Joomla! itself only connects to the database a single time. It uses the singleton pattern to either get the existing database connection or create it if needed.

It sounds like you have some custom code or a Joomla! extension is instantiating the JDatabase class multiple times. You shouldn't instantiate or deal with the class directly, instead you should use the `JFactory` to obtain the database object, which internally will either get the existing or create new if needed:

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
```

Comment: Can you please describe how Joomla manages the connection pool? How will it check the existing DB connection?

Comment: The connection is managed by `JFactory`. When some code needs the database, `JFactory` checks if it already has a connection object and if yes, return it, or if not then create a new connection and return it. Obviously this only works when all code is using `JFactory::getDBO()`. If some custom code is instantiating JDatabase directly then it will always create a new connection.

Comment: Also, Joomla! always creates a new database connection with each request, it doesn't share a connection across multiple requests. Also consider if ajax or other requests contribute to what your profiler is watching.

Comment: Thanks @MrCode, I am unable to understand your comment -  `Joomla! always creates a new database connection with each request, it doesn't share a connection across multiple requests.` It is leading to some confusion when read your first comment. Can you please clarify it?

Comment: To clarify, Joomla! creates a new database connection for each HTTP request to a page, that connection is then shared to any code that executes during the request, so 1 connection for 1 HTTP request. Some requests will not initiate the Joomla! core and so won't create a connection, for example images and CSS/Javascript.

Comment: Many Thanks @MrCode. Can you also broaden your answers by responding my other points?

Comment: To create database object, I have used everywhere in my custom extensions -  `$db = & JFactory::getDBO();`

Comment: Yes that is the correct way so you will either get a new connection or the existing connection.